# Exception not being Handled With Spring retry

Tags: java, spring, exception, spring-retry

I have a custom exception Called `MyException` which is being handled by the `MyExceptionHandler.class`

All worked well but then I needed to implement the **Spring Retry** on a function, but when  I did that the exception stopped being handled in that class here is a simple sample:

**My Custom Exception**

```
public class MyException extends RuntimeException {

    private String code;

    public MyException(String code) {
        super(code);
        this.code = code;
    }
}
```

**Exception Handler**

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class MyExceptionHandler extends RuntimeException{


@ExceptionHandler(RuntimeException.class)
    public Object handleError(RuntimeException ex) throws IOException {
       if(ex instanceof MyException){
          System.out.println("Handled")
       }
    }
}
```

**Retry Function**

```
@Retryable(exclude = MyException.class, include = TimeoutException.class, maxAttemptsExpression = "4",
        backoff = @Backoff(delayExpression = "100"))
public void retryFunction() {
    System.out.println("do something");
    throw new MyException("333");
}
```

I tried using `exclude` to make it ignore the exception but it stills throws and not handle it.

Any idea how I can make it work again.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean; `exclude` means don't retry these exceptions and go straight to the `@Recover` method (if there is one), otherwise the exception is thrown to the caller.

Comment: I could handle the exception manually in the `MyExceptionHandler` before putting the `@Retry` annotation, but now `recover` function or not, when the exception is thrown the `MyExceptionHandler` is not catching it, there is something the handler is not seeing that's why it's not handled but I can't figure it out.

Comment: @Makdous hod wid you handle this problem?
I have similar issue
Thanks.